# How do I conect my Java program to MySQL using HTTP?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to connect my Java program to my server but I can't. I don't want to use a localhost.

Comment: add some code maybe? explain what fails?

Comment: share your code will help you?

Comment: Are you using jdbc or what api are you using to connect to MySQL, could you please elaborate or provide a snippet on how you are connecting .

Comment: What on earth does HTTP have to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the hostname of the mysql server in the connection string instead of using localhost.  Make sure port 3306 is open on the mysql machine.  If you don't have a hostname use the IP address as a lassssst resort.  E.g.

192.168.1.20:3306

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-installing.html